# Алгоритм разбиения прямоугольника на маленькие прямоугольники

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

возникла проблема с реализацией следующей задачи(у меня есть прямоугольник скажем со случайными шириной и высотой и количеством на которое нужно его разбить):

```
// W=2 H=4 n=8

      |---------| (2;4)
      |         |
      |         |
      |         |
(0;0) |---------|
```

Я решил использовать бинарное дерево для этого:

```
function TreeNode(geometry) {
    this.leftChildNode = null;
    this.rightChildNode = null;
    this.geometry = geometry;
}

function createSquareGeometry(beginX, beginY, endX, endY) {
    return [
         [beginX, beginY],
         [endX, beginY],
         [endX, endY],
         [beginX, endY]
    ];
}

function generate(beginX, beginY, endX, endY, countFigures) {
    let treeNode = new TreeNode(createSquareGeometry(beginX, beginY, endX, endY));
    if (countFigures !== 1) {
        treeNode.leftChildNode = generate(beginX, beginY, endX / 2, endY / 2, countFigures / 2);
        treeNode.rightChildNode = generate(endX / 2, endY / 2, endX, endY, countFigures / 2);
    }
    return treeNode
}
```

Я бы хотел чтобы на каждой итерации алгоритм бил прямоугольник следующим образом:

```
1)    |---------| (2;4)
      |         |
      |         |
      |         |
(0;0) |---------|


2)    |---------| (2;4)
      |         |
      |---------|
      |         |
(0;0) |---------|

3)    |---------| (2;4)
      |         |
      |---------|
      |    |    |
(0;0) |---------|


4)    |---------| (2;4)
      |    |    |
      |---------|
      |    |    |
(0;0) |---------|

5) ...
```

Т.е. чтобы в случае нечетности, у меня были бы не все прямоугольники одинакового
размера, вопрос в том что я не могу правильно сконфигурировать рекурсию для этих целей, может кто-нибудь поможет с этим? А то уже не знаю что делать...

---

Обновлено для @tym32167

Вот мой код:

```
function divideRectangle(rectangle, countParts, geometry){
    if (countParts === 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (countParts === 1) {
        geometry.push(rectangle);
        return;
    }

    const leftCountParts = Math.floor(countParts / 2);
    const rightCountParts = countParts - 1;

    let newRectangle = null;
    if (rectangle.width > rectangle.height) {
        newRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangle.width / 2, rectangle.height);
    } else {
        newRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangle.width, rectangle.height / 2);
    }

    divideRectangle(newRectangle, leftCountParts, geometry);
    divideRectangle(newRectangle, rightCountParts, geometry);
}


const geometry = [];
const rectangle = new Rectangle(sheetWidth, sheetHeight);
divideRectangle(rectangle, 8, geometry);
console.log(geometry);
```

Comment: О каком "случае нечетности" идет речь? "Нечетности" чего?

Comment: @AnT я так понимаю когда нужно разбить на 5 прямоугольников область

Comment: Если W=2 H=4, и скажем количество фигур = 4, то должно получиться 4 одинаковых прямоугольника, а если количество скажем равно 3, то должно получиться(я прямоугольник равный 1/2 всей площади и два прямоугольника равных по 1/4 всей площади)

Comment: *скажем количество фигур = 4, то должно получиться 4 одинаковых прямоугольника* Почему **одинаковых**? Не вижу такого условия в исходной формулировке. *Я решил использовать бинарное дерево* Почему? *я не могу правильно сконфигурировать рекурсию* Задача в общем нерекурсионная - так что рекурсия при её решении как бы и не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писал на C#, надеюсь, будет и так всё ясно.

Определим класс прямоугольника

```
public class Rect
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Рекурсивная функция будет принимать прямоугольник, что надо разделить, количество частей, на сколько разделить, и аккумулятор, куда результат складывать.

```
public void DivideSquare(Rect source, int n, List<Rect> result)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        result.Add(source);
        return;
    }

    var l = n / 2;
    var r = n - l;

    Rect newSource = null;

    if (source.Width > source.Height)
        newSource = new Rect() { Width = source.Width / 2, Height = source.Height };
    else
        newSource = new Rect() { Width = source.Width, Height = source.Height / 2 };

    DivideSquare(newSource, l, result);
    DivideSquare(newSource, r, result);
}
```

Получается, делим на каждам шаге прямоугольник на 2. Проверка:

```
var ret = new List<Rect>();
var source = new Rect() {Height = 4, Width = 2};    
DivideSquare(source, 8, ret);   
foreach(var r in ret)
        Console.WriteLine($"{r.Width} - {r.Height}");
```

Вывод для раздбития прямоугольника 4х2 на 8 частей

```
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
```

На 7 частей

```
2 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 - 1
```

На 3 части

```
2 - 2
2 - 1
2 - 1
```

и тд

---

**UPD**

Конечно, если париться по расходу памяти, то можно на каждый чих и не создавать новый Rect, тогда функция будет выглядеть как то так

```
public void DivideSquare(int width, int height, int n, List<Rect> result)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        result.Add(new Rect() { Width = width, Height = height });
        return;
    }

    var l = n / 2;
    var r = n - l;

    int newWidth = width; 
    int newHeight = height; 

    if (width > height)
        newWidth/=2;
    else
        newHeight/=2;

    DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, l, result);
    DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, r, result);
}
```

Вызов будет как то так

```
var ret = new List<Rect>(); 
DivideSquare(2, 4, 8, ret);
foreach (var r in ret)
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Width} - {r.Height}");
```

Результат будет идентичен

---

**UPD 2**

Добавляем координаты к нашему решению (добавлю ко второму варианту, добавление к певрому будет домашним заданием)

Класс будет выглядеть так

```
public class Rect
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; } 
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
}
```

Метод для разбиения

```
public void DivideSquare(int width, int height, int top, int left, int n, List<Rect> result)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        result.Add(new Rect() { Width = width, Height = height, Top = top, Left = left });
        return;
    }

    var l = n / 2;
    var r = n - l;

    int newWidth = width;
    int newHeight = height;

    if (width > height)
    {
        newWidth /= 2;

        DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, top, left, l, result);
        DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, top, left + newWidth, r, result);

    }
    else
    {
        newHeight /= 2;
        DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, top, left, l, result);
        DivideSquare(newWidth, newHeight, top + newHeight, left, r, result);
    }
}
```

Тест

```
var ret = new List<Rect>();
DivideSquare(2, 4, 0, 0, 3, ret);
foreach (var r in ret)
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Top}:{r.Left}  {r.Width} - {r.Height}");
```

Результат

```
0:0  2 - 2
2:0  2 - 1
3:0  2 - 1
```

Comment: 0: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 1}
1: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 1}
2: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 1}
3: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 0.5}
4: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 0.5}
5: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 1}
6: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 0.5}
7: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 0.5}
8: Rectangle {width: 1, height: 0.5}
9: Rectangle {width: 0.5, height: 0.5}
10: Rectangle {width: 0.5, height: 0.5}
11: Rectangle {width: 0.5, height: 0.5}
...
17

Comment: У меня почему-то получается 18 наборов квадратов, вместо восьми, хотя все по идеи должно правильно работать...

Comment: @QuickDzen не знаю, как вы получаете 18 наборов, вы же ни кода, ничего не показываете. Вот если вы просто сопируете мой код и запустите, вы получите именно тот результат, что я указал.

Comment: l: 4
r: 7
l: 2
r: 3
l: 1
r: 1
l: 1
r: 2
l: 1
r: 1
l: 3
r: 6
l: 1
r: 2
l: 1
r: 1
l: 3
r: 5
l: 1
r: 2
l: 1
r: 1
l: 2
r: 4
l: 1
r: 1
l: 2
r: 3
l: 1
r: 1
l: 1
r: 2
l: 1
r: 1

Comment: Вывел в консоль 
var l = n / 2;
    var r = n - l;

Comment: Как ра-таки уже взял и скопировал ваш код

Comment: В какую сторону округляется выражение var l = n / 2, если приходит нечетное число в C#?

Comment: Обновил для вас вопрос, добавил туда свой код

Comment: @QuickDzen в меньшую. То есть 3/2=1. НО это компенсируется здесь `var r = n - l;`

Comment: Уже проверил это, я добавил код выше

Comment: @QuickDzen `const rightCountParts = countParts - 1;` ==> `const rightCountParts = countParts - leftCountParts ;`

Comment: Спасибо большое, как же схожи 1 и l, а можно еще помимо высоты и ширины прямоугольника добавлять его координаты относительно самого корневого прямоугольника? Это получается нужно еще один массив передавать, либо создавать дополнительные поля у класса?

Comment: @QuickDzen я бы просто поля добавил, что то типа `Top` и `Left` или `X`, `Y`

Comment: А не сможете добавить в коде, как это выглядело бы? А то с рекурсией еще плохо знаком...

Comment: @QuickDzen обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое)